# JSF2.0 richfaces 4.x Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I have my inputText in the form i can get its value by the following code

```
<h:inputText value="hello world" id="myidtest" />

alert($(#{rich:element('myidtest')}).val());
```

If i put my inputText under rich:datatable then `alert($(#{rich:element('myidtest')}).val());`

gives undefined after some r&D i found that rich:elment reference not returning object if it is under rich:datatable

any quick help appriciated

Comment: try getting the value with formId and datatable id rather than using inputText ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because each column will have a different generated id

Use columns tag to set the id based on the column index

```
<rich:columns value="#{dataTableScrollerBean.columns}" var="columns" index="ind" id="column#{ind}">
```

The generated id will look like `id="formId:tableId:rowIndex:column1"`

then you can use

```
jQuery(#{rich:element('formId:tableId:rowIndex:column1')}).
```

If that does not work post the generated html for that element.